# Login into Duolingo using Python Requests

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I want to land on the main (learning) page of my Duolingo profile but I am having a little trouble finding the correct way to sign into the website with my credentials using Python Requests.
I have tried making requests as well as I understood them but I am pretty much a noob in this so it has all went in vain thus far.
Help would be really appreciated!

This is what I was trying by my own means by the way:

```
#The Dictionary Keys/Values and the Post Request URL were taken from the Network Source code in Inspect on Google Chrome

import requests

headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = 
{
'identifier': 'something@email.com',
'password': 'myPassword'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/login?fields="
    s.post(url, headers = headers, params = login_data)
    r = s.get("https://www.duolingo.com/learn")
    print(r.content)
```

The post request receives the following content:

```
b'{"details": "Malformed JSON: No JSON object could be decoded", "error": "BAD_REQUEST_SCHEMA"}'
```

And since the login fails, the get request for the learn page receives this:

```
b'<html>\n <head>\n  <title>401 Unauthorized</title>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <h1>401
Unauthorized</h1>\n  This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser does not
understand how to supply the credentials required.<br/><br/>\n\n\n\n </body>\n</html>'
```

Sorry if I am making any stupid mistakes. I do not know a lot about all this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the POST request carefully you can see that:

- accepted content type is `application/json`
- there are more fields than you have supplied (`distinctId`, `landingUrl`)
- the data is sent as a json request body and not url params

<strike>The only thing that you need to figure out is how to get `distinctId` then you can do the following:</strike>

**EDIT:**

Sending email/password as json body appears to be enough and there is no need to get `distinctId`, example:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

data = {
    'identifier': 'something@email.com',
    'password': 'myPassword',
    }

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/login?fields="
    # use json.dumps to convert dict to serialized json string
    s.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    r = s.get("https://www.duolingo.com/learn")
    print(r.content)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Also, apparently, I did not need to add any headers and my data also did not need any `distinctID` or `landingUrl`. All I needed to use was `json.dumps()` for the parameters!